# Is there a standard definition of LPF stop band starting point in terms of dB attenuation

Tags: filter, low-pass

Below illustrates a LP filter bands:

[image]

I can say that the transition band starts at -3dB.
But the transition band ends at some point and there the stop band starts.
In this example it is -70dB they call this Stop Frequency above.

It seems that the transition band always starts at -3dB, but is there a consensus about the location of the beginning of the stop band(end of the transition band)? How is that quantified?(In the above case -70dB. Is that always -70dB? Who decides that? Or is this something about mathematical reasoning?)

Comment: where does that graph come from?

Comment: I might argue that the transition band starts before the cutoff frequency, as passband ends at pass frequency, after which the attenuation is more than the allowed passpand ripple.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for where a filter stopband starts.

This is because there are so many different applications for filters that almost *any* stopband will find a use somewhere. A deep stopband is expensive, to design, to make, and to test, so designers and filter buyers will always tend to use the shallowest stopband that meets the overall system specification.

For instance, if I had a signal in wideband white noise, and I wanted to reduce the total noise power, then I might be happy with only 10dB stopband.

If I wanted to visually remove harmonics from a display, 20dB might be plenty.

For telephony, a signal to noise ratio of 30dB is essentially indistinguishable from perfect.

Building a spectrum analyser, I might specify anything from 60dB for a hobby box to 90dB for the big name manufacturer.

Note that there's a difference between a theoretical filter frequency response, and the performance of a filter that you actually build. Although a Butterworth filter (for instance) goes down indefinitely in the stopband, once you build one, you find that stray coupling between input and output connectors, and stray inductance in the shunt components, limits how much stopband you actually get. Part of the difference between a cheap filter and an expensive one is (a) improving the layout and the components to minimise these problems and (b) testing with a good quality signal to prove that you have actually done it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes people will define something different for the start of the transition band.  For years in the last century, Tektronix specified it's spectrum analyzer bandwidths at the 6dB point.  But it's rare (and a lot of Tek old timers insist it hurt sales)
2. There is no consensus.  It pretty much depends on what your system needs are.
3. It is decided by a systems engineer, who looks at both the consequences of signals leaking through the stop band, and the expected expense of having a lower stop band (70dB gets difficult with analog electronics, and lower stop bands require wider data paths in digital filters), and makes a decision.
4. There isn't a mathematical basis in the sense that you can start with a few basic axioms and reason your way to The Perfect Stop Band.  It's more a case of a knowledgeable systems person with a spreadsheet, juggling numbers and arguing with the implementation people on one side and the marketing people on the other.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no standard, but like in your example the filter is well defined - there is a specification how much it must attenuate at stopband and at what frequency the stopband starts. Just like there is specification that how much there can be passband ripple and what the passband frequency is. It also defines the -3dB cutoff point frequency, but it is not always defined. Usually any filter that fits the passband and stopband template is acceptable, and least computationally expensive is selected.

Answer (score 0):

A filter's floor might be due to signals bypassing the filter, or due to its design. A simple analog example of a filter with a "floor" of about -40 dB...here, the term "transition band" has meaning (transition is from about 2Mhz - 10Mhz):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9ZRE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If L2 was insignificantly small, the floor would be very much improved. If L2 was eliminated entirely (very difficult in the real world), the attenuation slope would continue downward from the pass-band edge, and "transition band" would have no significance:
[image: attenuation plot at R2]

 For FIR digital filters, filter floors are somewhat similar to this form, very often with multiple points of high attenuation in the stop-band. *Transition band* has significant importance for these.